# What polynomial expansion is this? (sine)

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Reading through some articles on approximating the sine, I found this equation.

$\sin(x) / x = 1 - 0.16605 x^2 + 0.00761 x^4 + e(x)$

Those constants are different than what I'd expect from a Taylor series expansion (they should be 1/6 = 0.166667 and 1/120 = 0.0083333 respectively).  These constants also seem to give slightly better results than the Taylor series, so I'm really curious how they are derived.  Does anyone happen to know?

For the curious, the reference I got this from is Milton Abramowitz and Irene A. Stegun *Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables* published by Dover Press 1965.  That work cites "B. Carlson, M. Goldstein, *Rational approximations of functions* Los Alamos Scientific Laboratory, LA-1943, Los Alamos, NM, 1955."

Comment: Well, the constants are fairly close to the ones you'd expect, I guess...

Comment: Yes, I can see they are close.  But they do seem to work better, so I was wondering if there is a derivation for them other than maybe "dumb luck".

Comment: You can try to find the closest approximation by a quartic polynomial in a suitable norm, and for various possible choices of norm you'll get various different answers.

Comment: In addition to the good answers, the "Rational Approx..." reference you quote makes me think of [Pade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) approximation.

Comment: @icurays1. Not Padé approximant but close to curve fit with a very large number of data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you want the best approximation of $\frac{\sin(x)} x$ by a quadratic polynomial in $x^2$ with a constant term equal to $1$.

You then need to minimize with respect to $a,b$
$$I=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\left(\frac{\sin(x)} x -(1+ax^2+b x^4)\right)^2$$ which is equivalent to a linear regression with an infinite number of data points.

This gives $$I=\frac{1}{160} \pi ^5 \left(a^2+2 b\right)+\frac{1}{448} \pi ^7 a b-2 a+\frac{\pi ^3
   a}{12}+\frac{\pi ^9 b^2}{4608}-\frac{3}{2} \left(\pi ^2-8\right) b+\text{Si}(\pi
   )-2 \text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{2}{\pi }$$ Then $$\frac{dI}{da}=\frac{\pi ^5 a}{80}+\frac{\pi ^7 b}{448}+\frac{\pi ^3}{12}-2=0$$
$$\frac{dI}{db}=\frac{\pi ^7 a}{448}+\frac{\pi ^9 b}{2304}+\frac{1}{80} \left(960-120 \pi ^2+\pi
   ^5\right)=0$$ Solving for $a,b$ gives $$a=-\frac{56 \left(-3240+300 \pi ^2+\pi ^5\right)}{3 \pi ^7}\approx -0.166259$$ $$b=\frac{336 \left(-5040+480 \pi ^2+\pi ^5\right)}{5 \pi ^9}\approx 0.00773195$$

This leads to $I\approx 6.19\times 10^{-9}$ while using Taylor coefficients ($a=-\frac 16$, $b=\frac 1 {120}$) would lead to $I\approx 1.01\times 10^{-6}$ which is almost $163$ times larger. The values given in the referenced bood would lead to $I\approx 1.41\times 10^{-8}$.

But the results depend on the range over which you integrate.

Comment: what the what did you just what how did you integrate whAT i am conFuso

Comment: @SakethMalyala. This is the same as a linear regression with an infinite number of data points. The integral involves special functions.

Comment: This certainly *looks* correct although I didn't take the time to actually verify the math.  Thanks so much for taking the time to work this problem out!

Comment: @markspace. You are welcome ! May I confess my passion for function approximations ? By the way, just for the fun, I also made it for the next formula in the book (up to $x^{10}). It works but the formulas are probably more than a mile long ! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to compute functions on an interval, including power series. A great book about this is "Approximations for Digital Computers" by Cecil Hastings Jr. The approximation you gave probably came from Chebyshev Polynomials.

Comment: Well I knew about Taylor series and Lagrange polynomials, so I learned something new today at least.